# Java netbeans jlabel visibility when changing tabs

Tags: java, netbeans, jlabel

I am having a problem with my jframe gui program ... basically I created a gui with 2 tabs (Home & About) .. and I can switch between the tabs easily which works fine. I also put a button in the about tab which when I click , a pop up appears. Now I want that pop up to stay there even if I switch tabs .. my problem is when I go to the home tab and go back to the about tab , the pop up is gone (I have to click the button again) ,   I was wondering if there is a way to make it stay there. This is a gif showing my exact problem

[image]

any help will be highly appreciated!! thanks :)

Comment: here https://gyazo.com/3f55f94caa4d79032da80f414ae218e2 jlabel 5 is the pop up

Comment: very difficult to understand form the code you post ... paste code that can be compiled... anyway i would check 2 things : 1-maybe need to paint() or repaint() 2- maybe create the same popup again or pass it between jframes/jpanels